# Integrate rust-clippy into Emacs Rust development

Tags: rust

[`rust-clippy`](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy) is a linter for Rust. Is there an existing package or idiom that integrates it into an Emacs Rust workflow, the way `emacs-racer` integrates `racer`?

Comment: You can consider integrate rust-clippy into flycheck.

Answer (score 2):

Since `rust-clippy` normally works at compile time, it should get integrated into whatever you are using for compiling Rust code in Emacs (e.g. `cargo-minor-mode`). This is touched on [in this blog post](http://julienblanchard.com/2016/fancy-rust-development-with-emacs/) on setting up Emacs for Rust, in case you have not seen it already.

Answer (score 2):

When you use rust-analyzer via lsp-mode you can tell it to use clippy as the default linter via `(setq lsp-rust-analyzer-cargo-watch-command "clippy")` (normally it would use check).

The config presented in this [guide](https://robert.kra.hn/posts/2021-02-07_rust-with-emacs/) uses it by default.